# Tensorflow windows error

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I am trying to install tensorflow(GPU) for windows using Python 3.5 but I get error when I try to import the tensorflow package.

```
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:119] Couldn't open CUDA library cublas64_80.dll
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_blas.cc:2294] Unable to load cuBLAS DSO.
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:119] Couldn't open CUDA library cudnn64_5.dll
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_dnn.cc:3459] Unable to load cuDNN DSO
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:119] Couldn't open CUDA library cufft64_80.dll
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_fft.cc:344] Unable to load cuFFT DSO.
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library nvcuda.dll locally
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:119] Couldn't open CUDA library curand64_80.dll
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_rng.cc:338] Unable to load cuRAND DSO.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you follow the instructions for installing CUDA Toolkit? You can find a link to the instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows).

> Requirements to run TensorFlow with GPU support
>
> If you are installing TensorFlow with GPU support using one of the
> mechanisms described in this guide, then the following NVIDIA software
> must be installed on your system:
>
> CUDA® Toolkit 8.0. For details, see NVIDIA's documentation
>
> Ensure that you append the relevant Cuda pathnames to the %PATH% environment
> variable as described in the NVIDIA documentation.
>
> The NVIDIA drivers
> associated with CUDA Toolkit 8.0. cuDNN v5.1. For details, see
> NVIDIA's documentation. Note that cuDNN is typically installed in a
> different location from the other CUDA DLLs.
>
> Ensure that you add the
> directory where you installed the cuDNN DLL to your %PATH% environment
> variable. GPU card with CUDA Compute Capability 3.0 or higher. See
> NVIDIA documentation for a list of supported GPU cards.

Comment: Yeah there was an error in the compatibility. Thanks for the help :)